What are volumes 3 and 4 of _Shemirath Shabbath_ about?
Shemirath Shabbath is the English translation of a work by Rabbi Yehoshua Neuwirth.  The books explain how to keep Shabbat.  They also explain the halacha regarding modern conveniences such as fridges and escalators on Shabbat.  The books are somewhat dated now, but still mostly useful.
Volumes 1 and 2 were published in the '80s, and are perhaps still most commonly found in shul libraries.
Volumes 3 and 4 are newer, and I don't own them.  What are they about?

Yaacov Deane posted an image of the volume 3 back cover.
Ebay user zamoratk posted an image of the volume 4 back cover.
Volume 3 covers:

Preparing for Shabbat and Yom Tov.
Kiddush.
Havdalah.
Melaveh Malkah.
Mourning on Shabbat and Yom Tov.
Chol Ha'moed.

Volume 4 includes:

A translation of "Principles of the Laws of Shabbat and Yom Tov", from the third Hebrew volume; this explains the underlying principles of the book.
A complete index to volumes 1–3 of the English translation.
A separate index to the laws of Chol Ha'moed.
Typographic corrections, clarifications and additions to the previous two volumes.
A glossary of English translations of some of the more obscure Hebrew terms used by the author.
A concordance between Shemirath Shabbath to Shulchan Aruch and several other halachic sources used by the author. (Source.)

Volume 4 isn't sold on the publisher's website. I suspect it's currently out of print. Perhaps it didn't sell well, and was therefore discontinued. You can still find it if you search on Google and Ebay. Or you can request an interlibrary loan from your local library; this may be free of charge.
(Does volume 3 include any index? Please edit this answer and tell us, then delete this paragraph of commentary. Thanks in advance!)
Part of this answer is thanks to Yaacov Deane.

This is a photo of the back cover of volume 3. It gives a brief summary of its contents which cover chapters 42 through 68 of the original Hebrew edition. It states that it is the final volume of the English edition.
What you are calling volume 4 to the English edition is a separate book of typographic corrections, clarifications and additions to the previous two volumes, indices, glossary of English translations of some of the more obscure modern Hebrew terms used by the author and a concordance between Shemirath Shabbat to Shulchan Aruch and several other halachic sources used by the author.
At the end of the volume 3 table of contents it says a separate, fourth volume is available. I have only found it in the original Hebrew. The exact wording about the the index volume is:

Comprehensive index to volumes I, II and III appear in a separate volume.



After volume 4 was finally published, volume 3 ceased to be the final volume.

@unforgettableidSupportsMonica Have you actually seen an English translation of the fourth volume of indices and corrigenda? I have seen no evidence anywhere that it ever got translated.

I think volume 4 was published in English some time ago, but was not very popular, and is now out of print.  Some used-book vendors sometimes have copies for sale.  You may view an image of the English volume 4 back cover; it was posted online by Ebay user zamoratk.
